# Can we say "I am having a Covid shot tomorrow"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

The verb "**have**" has many meanings. Some of its meanings can be used in continuous tenses, its other tenses can not be used in continuous tenses.

For example, "**I am having a great time**" ("**have**" means to experience in this case)

But, "**I have flu**" ("**have**" means to "suffer from" in this case)

What does the verb "**have**" in this sentence "**have a Covid shot**" mean?

Can we say "**I am having a Covid shot tomorrow**"?

Answer (score 3):

It means *experience the action happening* or *cause something to be done to you by someone else.*

Yes, we can say **I am having a Covid shot tomorrow** (or **getting**).

Comment: I think *getting* is more likely. I'm having dinner, but I'm getting a shot.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty Agreed - I think the difference is that "having" sounds like more of a long-term process - it takes some time to eat dinner, while "getting" is a single event - the actual shot takes seconds.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I also agree I would use getting and not having, but I'm having (haha) a hard time putting my finger on why. I think it may be because *getting* means *obtaining*, as in "I am getting groceries tomorrow." where *having* would mean owning which would actually be limited by the time "tomorrow"... "I am going to get a car tomorrow" (I will buy it tomorrow, it will be mine until future notice) vs "I am going to have a car tomorrow" (I probably won't have it day after tomorrow for some reason, maybe it was only a rental).

Answer (score 1):

The sentence *"I am having a Covid shot tomorrow"* is fine. The word *"shot"* is commonly used in UK English to denote an injection.

I believe that the intended meaning is *"an anti-Covid shot"* or even better a *"a Covid vaccination"*. However, the phrase *"a Covid shot"* works well as no one (except a few research scientists) would want to inject the actual disease.

Comment: I would say that for many Brits, 'shot' for injection still has a distinct whiff of being an Americanism. We have seen much use of 'jab' in the UK press.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - and apparently Americans find 'jab' strange (or did at the start of the pandemic) - https://separatedbyacommonlanguage.blogspot.com/2020/12/2020-uk-to-us-word-of-year-jab.html

Comment: While "an anti-Covid shot" is more technically accurate saying "a Covid shot" I don't think there is much chance of being misunderstood in this context. No one is getting a shot that gives them Covid (I would hope), so either would be interpreted the same way. I've certainly heard native english speakers use both

Comment: @KateBunting I think that's because we associate "jab" with a punch, either literally (e.g. in a fistfight/boxing match) or figuratively (e.g. small verbal insults).  Not something you want to be on the receiving end of in either case.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - Neither do you want to be on the receiving end of a (gun)shot! It all depends on which term you are used to.